# How to fetch data after n interval of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have data stored of every 1 seconds in sql server, i need to fetch data of every 1 or 2 minute interval not of seconds,how can I get data every 2 minutes based using SQL?

[image: here is an example]

[image: here is sql code]

Comment: Your date columns have lots of duplicates.  Why is there no seconds component?

Comment: I added table format..

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
(
    select *, 
       datepart(minute, yourDate) mn, 
       row_number() over(partition by datepart(minute, yourDate) order by yourDate) rn
    from yourTable
) x
where (mn % 2) = 0
    and rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition convert(date, datecol), datepart(hour, datecol), datepart(minute, datecol) / 2
                                order by datecol
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `partition by` is breaking the data into groups of two-minutes each (the `/ 2` does that).  The logic then returns the first record in each group.